# Sublime text 2 php highlighting between Javascript/jQuery

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

How to highlight only PHP code in Sublime Text 2 between Javascript/jQuery? Because I need to recognize PHP with easy between Javascript/jQuery.
At the moment I use in my theme:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded source</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text source.php</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#d4d7ae</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Embedded source</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>text source.js</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>background</key>
            <string>#F2F2F2</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

I want exactly the same thing like this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592226/sublime-text-2-highlighting-like-netbeans) also check my screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/sfs5n4jv3/)